# Why brew bump-formula-pr raises "version_schemes should only increment by 1" when a version scheme is not changed

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to create a PR for a newly released version and see the following:

```sh
$ brew bump-formula-pr --strict --tag=0.8.0 --revision=7a5bd5b3a318aeba568f7b467d7364699e6160fb elegant-git
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
No changes to formulae.

==> replace "0.7.0" with "0.8.0"
==> replace "5fc093508a8337a8c60c1b339ea2d93201ee357e" with "7a5bd5b3a318aeba568f7b467d7364699e6160fb"
bees-hive/hive/elegant-git:
  * version_schemes should only increment by 1
Error: 1 problem in 1 formula detected
Error: brew audit failed!
```

From [the official documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/Homebrew/brew/Formula#version_scheme=-class_method):

> if we want to change version scheme from one to another, then we may need to update `version_scheme` of this Formula to be able to use new version scheme.

As I don't change the versioning scheme, it should work. But there is an error. **Why does this happen? And any ideas on how to fix it?**

I'm trying to update [Elegant Git formulae](https://github.com/bees-hive/homebrew-hive/blob/master/Formula/elegant-git.rb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the audit since homebrew-core never had to bump version schemes more than once. See https://discourse.brew.sh/t/why-brew-bump-formula-pr-raises-version-schemes-should-only-increment-by-1-when-a-version-scheme-is-not-changed/5805?u=extsoft for details.